# Does Ruby's "raise" modify exception?

Tags: ruby, exception

Does Ruby's "raise" modify exception?

Or, are following snippets:

```
some_method(MyException.new)
```

and

```
begin
  raise MyException.new
rescue MyException => e
  some_method(e)
end
```

equivalent?  If not, what are the differences?

Comment: Any data that made you consider that?

Comment: @Tass — Every exception is bound to some execution context, backtrace… I thought it could be modified when thrown.

Comment: yes, backtrace is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent.

```
begin
  e = Exception.new "AAA"
  puts e.backtrace.nil?
  raise e
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.backtrace.nil?
end
```

gives

```
true
false
```

Does anyone know other differences?

**EDIT:**

`Kernel#raise` WILL NOT modify exception unless `raise` is called with no params and `$!` is defined (that means: except re-raising exception in `rescue` clause with no params).  In following example:

```
begin
  raise "exception" #1
rescue
  raise #2
end
```

exception will be modified (its context and backtrace altered) in #1 raise but untouched in #2 raise.  It WILL be modified in any other case, including re-raising exception with some param like:

```
begin
  raise "exception" #1
rescue Exception => e
  raise e #2
end
```

Here exception will be altered in both #1 and #2.

See https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/delta/kernel.rb for details.

Above applies to Rubinius.  It should be the same in MRI 1.9 and JRuby, but I haven't checked it.